# Updating different columns of many rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to do this from Python to Snowflakes:

```
UPDATE 'table'
SET column1 = 'XXX'
WHERE id = 123;
                     
UPDATE 'table'
SET column2 = 'YYY'
WHERE id = 145;

...

UPDATE 'table'
SET column256 = 'YYY'
WHERE id = 654;
```

But I don't want to open hundreds of connections. Is it possible to structure this update in one single query and send to database only one statement?

It is always the same table but different columns to update.

Comment: how many total updates?  how many distinct ids?  how many distinct columns?

Comment: yes use inner join to update the multiple column rows by comparing the primary key as foreign key

Comment: removed mysql tag; snowflake is not mysql

Comment: @ysth It will be between 500-5000 each time the script works

Comment: which will be 500-5000?  I asked three questions

Comment: 500-5000  updates, each one with a distinct id. Around 80 columns.

Comment: You can execute many statements using python without opening more than one connection. If you show your Python code we may be able to help

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `values` and conditional logic:

```
UPDATE table t
    SET column1 = (CASE WHEN col = 'column1' THEN v.value ELSE column1 END),
        column2 = (CASE WHEN col = 'column2' THEN v.value ELSE column2 END),
        column256 = (CASE WHEN col = 'column256' THEN v.value ELSE column256 END)        
    FROM (VALUES (123, 'XXX', 'column1'),
                 (145, 'YYY', 'column2'),
                 (654k, 'YYY', 'column256')
         ) v(id, value, col)
    WHERE t.id = v.id
```

Comment: hi @Gordon Linoff , are you suggesting to create one lookup table ?

Comment: @PIG . . . You could.  But you can just use a derived table in the query.